# QCLCD vs. ISD Lite for U.S. data

Tags: weather, noaa

I'm interested in using a [NOAA](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access) dataset for daily/hourly weather data for the U.S.

Both the [QCLCD](http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/orders/qclcd/) and [ISD Lite](http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/isd-lite/) datasets contain the variables in which I'm interested for the time frame with which I'm concerned (QCLCD is only post-2005). However, I can't find any information about their differences in terms of coverage, construction, etc. in the U.S.

Does anyone have experience working with/understand the differences between these two datasets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I emailed the NOAA and got a very fast response from William Brown:

> Both the QCLCD and ISD digital surface hourly data bases contain the
>   same stations.  QCLCD is a 'subset" of the much larger (global) ISD
>   data base. Typically for research purposes I would recommend ISD.  You
>   can download the data in bulk and, due to format differences only, the
>   period of record is longer for ISD.

So, it looks like the U.S. coverage for both is the same and that both are constructed from full ISD dataset.